# Serverless VPC Access connector with a "VPC with multiple Subnets"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sql-server-2008-r2, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I have the following scenario:

- VPC network with one subnet that has 2 VMs with SQL Server installed (both have same data).
- Serverless VPC Access connector
- Cloud Run Service (Django container)

My code in Django is successfully able to connect to the 2 SQL Servers through the Serverless VPC Access connector.

Now I wanted to create another SQL Server VM in another region, so I created another subnet for the new region inside my VPC.

The 3 SQL Servers can connect to each other.

The Cloud Run service is still able to connect to the original subnet with the 2 SQLs, but when I try to connect to the new SQL Server, I am getting "Login timeout expired"!

Is there something I need to do to allow the traffic from the cloud run service to the new SQL Server in the new subnet?

Thank you.

Update:

Here are details:

[image: VPC]
[image: Connector]

Comment: Google Cloud VPCs are global. Why did you create another subnet (which is not necessary)? Edit your question and show the VPC, subnets, and VPC connectors.

Comment: I create another subnet in the VPC because I wanted to create the new SQL Server in a new region, also I updated the question.

Comment: Valid VPC IP address are 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16. You created addresses that are **public**. VPC addresses cannot be public as those are reserved by other IP address holders and cannot be routed within your VPC. For example, 12.0.0.0/8 is owned by AT&T. 11.0.0.0/8 is owned by the US Department of Defense.

Comment: You were right! I changed the subnet for the new region and it is working now, Thank you very much!.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have copied your comment to the answers sections as leaving the answer in comments leaves questions open even though it has correct answers in comments. Please See [what if i answer a question in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment)

Comment: @AtefH. - I did not post an answer yet as I think there is something else wrong as well. I am not sure due to the lack of details. Your answer is good at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the following answer from comments:

As mentioned by **[@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley)**

> Valid VPC IP addresses are 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16.
> You have created addresses that are **public**. VPC addresses cannot be public
> as those are reserved by other IP address holders and cannot be routed
> within your VPC. For example, 12.0.0.0/8 is owned by AT&T. 11.0.0.0/8
> is owned by the US Department of Defense.